# Rigify elbow doesn't rotate fully

Tags: workflow, rigify

I'm trying to rotate the elbow of a character I imported from Daz to Blender. For some reason the rotation stops when the angle reaches 90 degrees between the bones and I can't rotate it more. I tried to remove all the constraints but to no avail.

I tried to edit the armature but for some reason it didn't move at all.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: hello maybe share your armature (upload your file and copy paste the URL it will generate): https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: I uploaded the blend file to this address: https://pasteall.org/blend/6f85df765d794232826f596a34ecd0a4
Notice that the left elbow doesn't fully rotate.

Answer (score 0):

This DAZ rig has some additional bone constraints that the unmodified Rigify rig does not have.

If there are bone constraints on the bones of the metarig then Rigify uses them for the generated rig. It copies the metarig to layer 30. These bones become the *ORG-* bones. Then, among other things, the FK control bones are generated, which also receive the bone constraints of the original bones.

The *DEF-* bones deform the mesh and the control bones control the *DEF-* bones at the end. But between this relationship, there are several layers with other bones like *MCH-*, *Tweak*, and *ORG-*, and numerous bone constraints that copy the transformations, as well as *Child-Of* constraints and *Parent* relationships that also affect the transformations.

Now you have turned off the bone constraints for the FK control bones that limit their rotation, but the other bone constraints are still active for the *ORG-* bones, which are involved in controlling the *DEF-* bones. So the bone constraints on the ORG- bones still restrict the rotation of the arms.

[image: bone contraints (ORG bones)]

**The solution is to disable the *Limit Rotation* bone constraints of the *ORG-* bones as well.** The bones are *ORG-forearm.L* and *ORG-upper_arm.L* by name for the left arm, and **.R* for the right arm. They are on the last bone layer. The "eye icon" enables/disables the bone constraint.

[image: disabled bone contraints (ORG bones)]

Comment: It worked! thanks